# Weka class attribute suggestion

Tags: decision-trees

We are trying to run J48 on a classified data set. Our class attribute has two possible values ( 0,1) when running J48 the tree terminates at the very first node and doesnt process any further.

Instead of considering (0- false) as the starting point of J48. How can we consider running J48 by selecting (1-true) as the starting point of the tree?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might occur if J48 decides it cannot find meaningful nodes. What is the a priori distribution of the classes and how high is your confidence parameter (C)?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have only 1 attribute (numeric).
What you can do is

1. modify the .arff file and set 0s to 1 and 1s to 0.
2. Then you can again run j48 classifier and visualise the decision tree.

It would give you inverted result.
Also, try watching this video.[WEKA on MOOC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7R9NHqvI0Y)